# JavaScript Authenticator with Keycloak 18

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have upgraded my server in my Dev environment to version 18. We have a requirement of using a JavaScript authenticator.
As per the [new documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_script_providers), I have created a JAR file and copied it in **/providers** directory and did a **kc.sh build --features=scripts**.
I get the following output (the one in bold is the JAR file for JS authenicator), However in the GUI I do not see my script under authenticator.

What else is required to use JS authenticator?

```html
root@2f50c05d580b:/opt/keycloak/keycloak-18.0.2/providers# ../bin/kc.sh show-config
Current Mode: none
Runtime Configuration:
kc.cache = ispn (PersistedConfigSource)
kc.config.args = show-config (SysPropConfigSource)
kc.db = dev-file (PersistedConfigSource)
kc.features = preview (PersistedConfigSource)
kc.health-enabled = false (PersistedConfigSource)
kc.home.dir = /opt/keycloak/keycloak-18.0.2/bin/../ (SysPropConfigSource)
kc.http-enabled = false (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/keycloak-18.0.2/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.2.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
kc.http-relative-path = / (PersistedConfigSource)
kc.log-console-output = default (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/keycloak-18.0.2/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.2.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
kc.log-file = /opt/keycloak/keycloak-18.0.2/bin/../data/log/keycloak.log (PropertiesConfigSource[source=jar:file:///opt/keycloak/keycloak-18.0.2/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-quarkus-server-18.0.2.jar!/META-INF/keycloak.conf])
kc.metrics-enabled = false (PersistedConfigSource)
kc.provider.file.ammauth3.jar.last-modified = 1658319279100 (PersistedConfigSource)
kc.quarkus-properties-enabled = false (PersistedConfigSource)
kc.show.config = none (SysPropConfigSource)
kc.version = 18.0.2 (SysPropConfigSource)
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Yes. Two things (1) you cannot enable scripts in Dev mode so I had to run the Keycloak in PROD mode (2) only works till OpenJDK 11. If you have any version beyond 11 then it wont work.